# How could I run PHP-FPM master process as non-root user?

Tags: permissions, docker, php-fpm, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to achieve rootless PHP-FPM pod running in Kubernetes.

I tried simply running process in Kubernetes pod via init script that does `php-fpm -FO` as `www-data` user but it complaints about not having permissions to access `/dev/stderr` (*log output location*). Adding `www-data` user to the `tty` group also didn't help.

I tried specifying another location like `/proc/self/fd/2` and even `/dev/pts/1` as log location but to no avail.

Funny thing is, when I run `docker run -itd app:latest su -l www-data -s /bin/sh -c php-fpm -FO &`, basically the same startup command via Docker directly, it starts and works just fine.

I don't have any `securityContext` configured in Kubernetes that could affect process from starting normally.

Any suggestions/ideas to try?

Comment: Can you share more details? Which node OS and container image are you using?

Comment: @Sergiusz I use GKE and their cOS OS and php:fpm-alpine image.

Answer (score 0):

If you experience the same error on different public apps, it may indicate an issue with GKE. You can report it via [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).
If this error is specific to this app, consider different logging aggregator, for example the [sidecar pattern](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-operating-containers#log_aggregator_sidecar_pattern).
There's more information regarding logging on GKE in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/using-logging-your-apps-running-kubernetes-engine).
Additionally, if you are using cOS with Docker, you should switch to containerd version because the former has been [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#cos-variants).